# Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I'm using android studio 3.0.1, when I start my emulator I get many error messages, I've tried to solve each problem separately, I also searched a lot but nothing works for me.

```
12:24 م Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!

12:24 م Emulator: OpenGL backend 'angle' without OpenGL ES 1.x library 
detected. Using GLESv2 only.

12:24 م Emulator: Failed to eglInitialize

12:24 م Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

12:24 م Emulator: Warning: requested RAM 1024M too high for your system. 
Reducing to maximum supported size 512M

12:25 م Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, 
use '-gpu off' to disable it.

12:25 م Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I also tried [this](http://www.errorlive.com/exception-code-0xc0000005)

Answer (score 13):

**Make sure your graphics driver is updated**

1. Go to **tools**
2. Go to **Android**
3. Select **AVD Manager**.

[image]

4. click on the **pencil icon** in under Action
5. Click **Advanced Settings** button.
6. In Emulated Performance row change Graphics to **Software GLES 2.0**
7. In Memory, row change RAM field to 512(minimum).

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I'm using all those settings already .. any idea?

Comment: Is 512 MB enough? I'd think it needs at least 2 GB.

Comment: Nothing happens by this

Comment: `Tools -> Device Manager` is the path to this with Andoid Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1

Answer (score 10):

I modified the avd config file and solved a similar problem.

1. find your avd folder.(If your using Windows OS, the default path is `C:\Users\USER_NAME\ .android\avd\YOUR_VIRTUAL_DEVICE_NAME.avd`)
2. open the file `config.ini`
3. find `hw.gpu.mode` and set it to `off` (`hw.gpu.mode=off`)
4. launch the AVD manager
5. launch your virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

check in your emulator setting `Use Host GPU` enabled shown in below image

[image]

this will you get `Android Studio -> Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager` here

Comment: theres no such choice

Comment: there's no such choice http://www7.0zz0.com/2017/12/04/14/221642339.png

Comment: try graphics options with **Hardware - GLES 2.0**

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. In my case, running Android Studio as an administrator solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still having issues after trying these things, note that there is a ongoing issue with the Android plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (but Android Studio works).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-231313

Workaround is to run the `.bat` file from the IntellJ installation path.