# Cannot set up the virtual device in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am new to android studio. And i am trying to set up a virtual device for my project. One the virtual device is created and when i run it virtual device is not displaying and it gives me following errors.How can i resolve this in order to run the virtual device.

Errors as follows

```
10:06 AM    Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

10:06 AM    Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!

10:06 AM    Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!

10:06 AM    Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!

10:06 AM    Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

10:06 AM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

10:06 AM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: try to disable hardware acceleration, look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration) for details

Comment: I meet a similar problem, you can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51740954/10195941) for detail.