# Android Studio: Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-device-manager

I am encountering a new problem with Android Studio, to be precise with the Virtual Device.

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 on a Computer with an AMD Ryzen CPU.
I encountered a lot of problems already due to the CPU but fixed all of them until now because I can't find any similiar case to mine.

So as long as I program in Android Studio everything works fine. When I then try to run the app, first things get strange because it takes quite long and my computer is pretty fast usually. Still there is no problem, after a while the App will be loaded on my AVD and display correctly.
**BUT** if I press a button, which displays something in the log onclick, it just closes and shows me the error: "Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)".

can someone help me please!

Best regards

Comment: This is possibly memory issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631771/emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc0000005)

Comment: do u have any tipps for me @¦femin dharamshi

Comment: @steven no its not! i saw and watched through the post, tried even some solutions but nothing worked for me

Comment: Increase your memory allocation for emulator.