# Android Studio - unable to open emulator, finished with exit code -1073741819

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, bios, avd-manager

I'm new to mobile development. Just installed Android Studio v3.5.3 and trying to setup the emulator.
On opening the AVD manager, it listed one device - *AVD GalaxyNexus ToolsForApacheCordova*, that I downloaded.

After it was downloaded, there was a message - *Vt-x disabled in BIOS*.
I enabled that setting in BIOS and now when I click on the play icon for this device, it shows the error.

> Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

**Steps I have tried so far:**

1. Cold Boot Now option - still shows the same error.
2. Changed the Graphics selection to Automatic from Software. It showed an alert that said something about x86 recommended, displayed the emulator for a few seconds and then stopped. Not worked again after that.
3. Increased the RAM to 1 GB in the settings, for this device.

This is a Windows X64 machine with 16GB RAM.

[image]

Comment: does [Android Studio Emulator and “Process finished with exit code 0”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739661/android-studio-emulator-and-process-finished-with-exit-code-0) answer your question?

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee Unfortunately, it didn't

Comment: Are you running it as Administrator? I see from the image that Android Studio is, but does that include the VDM?

Comment: Also, is there any more information in the Events that lead up to the exit error?

Comment: maybe does [Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47631771/11348074) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to be with the default suggested device (AVD GalaxyNexus ToolsForApacheCordova).

I deleted that & added a new virtual device - Nexus 4.

It worked!